# Vertically align a Bootstrap Col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align vertically a small boostrap column cell...

The idea is that I can't hardcode something in pixel (`height, line-height`, by eg), everything should be relative, cause I don't know a priori the green cell height (variable by content).

The `top +50 & translateY -50` doesn't seem to work...

The [CodePen is here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/rwBxbR?editors=1100). The code is bellow:

```css
.a{background: lightgreen;}
.b{background: yellow;}
.cont {background:orange;}
.vcenter {top: 50%; transform:translateY(-50%);}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-xs-12 cont">
  <div class="a col-xs-8">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150">
    some description
  </div>
  <div class="b vcenter col-xs-4">
    This should be middle aligned vertically!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had only an answer from you Pete, thank you, the @tsdln answer does not fit the initial OP conditions...

Comment: This would be a valid answer then: impossible to do in CSS, change the display, OK, but not for the container

Comment: @Pete could you please repost your answer with the flex?! Maybe I can use it, finally, with some changes to fit the flex display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Pete found a solution that need however to affect the display of the container:

```
.cont { display: flex; }
.vcenter { align-self: center; }
```